# Complex Event Processing (CEP) with Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, stream, correlation

There are some stream processing frameworks that allow for complex event processing and correlation (like for example http://esper.codehaus.org/).

When it comes to Ruby/Rails (in particular running on heroku), I could not find a suitable/comparable solution.

Any ideas/suggestion how to get the power of stream processing and in particular event correlation by means of gem install?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at a similar challenge and haven't found a direct analog to Esper in the Rails world. That said, the Pub/Sub capabilities of Redis (see http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) seem to be doing the trick for me so far, and I recommend you see whether they might (even partially) satisfy your use case.